Derivative on the boundary and finite volume
I am doing a solution of a PDE, and I'm solving it using the finite volume method. I have a  Robin condition and I need to approximate the derivative on the boundary. Naively I write:
$$\frac{df}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=0}=\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h}$$
For the finite-volume the approximation is taken at the mid-point of the cell, so this can be written as: $$\frac{df}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=0}=\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h/2)-f(x+h)}{h}$$
As $f(x)$ and $f(x+h)$ are on the boundaried of the cell (rather than the cell centre). Can I then use further approximations to compute the values at the boundaries? for example:
$$f(x+h)\approx\frac{f(x+h/2)+f(x+3h/2)}{2}$$

Suppose I write:
$$f'(x)=af(x)+bf(x+h/2)+cf(x+3h/2)$$
I then use Taylor series to get the equation:
$$f'(x)=(a+b+c)f(x)+\frac{h}{2}(b+3c)f'(x)+\frac{h^{2}}{8}(b+9c)f''(x)$$
Equating coefficients reduces to the following set of linear equations:
$$a+b+c=0,\quad b+3c=\frac{2}{h},\quad b+9c=0$$
The solution of these equations are:
$$a=-\frac{8}{3h},\quad b=\frac{3}{h},\quad c=-\frac{1}{3h}$$
Hence:
$$f'(x)=-\frac{8}{3h}f(x)+\frac{3}{h}f(x+h/2)-\frac{1}{3h}f(x+3h/2)$$
Does this make sense? I tried it with a few functions, and it seems to work reasonably well.
